# ¿Cómo insertar un elemento en la mitad de una lista Prolog?

Tags: lista, prolog

He buscado información en la red, respecto a como insertar un elemente a la mitad de una lista en Prolog, pero no he encontrado información relevante respecto a lo que quiero hacer.

%Cree_un_programa_en_Prolog_que_inserte_un_elemento_en_la_mitad_de_una_lista
%insertar_mitad([a,b,c,d,e,f],x,R).
%R=[a,b,c,x,d,e,f].

Soy nuevo utilizando el programa de Prolog y aprendiendo su lógica. además, les soy sincero es un ejercicio de la universidad y no se como desarrollarlo, gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar lo que has intentado hasta el momento? Sería bueno que editaras tu pregunta e incluyeras tu código a modo de [mcve], de este modo tu pregunta será mejor recibida, puedes hacerlo haciendo clic sobre el botón de [edit]. Adicionalmente te invito a leer [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para insertar en la mitad de una lista podes recorrer la lista a dos "velocidades": una avanzando de a un elemento y la otra avanzando de a dos elementos a la vez.

De esta manera cuando llegues al final de la segunda lista la primera va a estar en la mitad. En ese momento podes agregar el elemento que quieras en el medio junto con la otra mitad de la lista.

```
insertar_mitad(L, E, R):-
  insertar_mitad(L, L, E, R).
  
insertar_mitad([], L, E, [E|L]).
insertar_mitad([_], L, E, [E|L]).
insertar_mitad([_, _|L], [Item|L2], E, [Item|R]):-
  insertar_mitad(L, L2, E, R).
```

La segunda cláusula de insertar_mitad/4 cubre el caso de listas de cantidad impar. Si se quita el procedimiento solamente sucederá para lista de cantidad par de elementos.

Casos de prueba:

```
?- insertar_mitad([a,b,c,d,e,f],x,R).
R = [a, b, c, x, d, e, f].

?- insertar_mitad([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],x,R).
R = [a, b, c, x, d, e, f, g] ;
false.
```

---

Para evitar dejar alternativas se puede agregar otro procedimiento auxiliar para ayudar al indexado:

```
insertar_mitad(L, E, R):-
  insertar_mitad(L, L, E, R).
  
insertar_mitad([], L, E, [E|L]).
insertar_mitad([_|L], L2, E, R):-
  insertar_mitad1(L, L2, E, R).

insertar_mitad1([], L, E, [E|L]).
insertar_mitad1([_|L], [Item|L2], E, [Item|R]):-
  insertar_mitad(L, L2, E, R).
```

En el que ahora vemos que el segundo ejemplo no deja alternativas:

```
?- insertar_mitad([a,b,c,d,e,f],x,R).
R = [a, b, c, x, d, e, f].

?- insertar_mitad([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],x,R).
R = [a, b, c, x, d, e, f, g].
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%caso base de insertar
insertar(E,L,1,[E|L]).
%caso recursivo
insertar(E,[Ca|Resto],Pos,[Ca|R]):-
   Pos>1, Pos1 is Pos-1,
   insertar(E,Resto,Pos1,R).

%caso base de longitud
longitud([],0).
longitud([Ca|Resto], N1):-
  longitud(Resto,N),
  N1 is N+1.

%insertar en la mitad
insertar_mitad(L,E,R):-
  longitud(L,N),
  N2 is div(N+1,2)+1,
  insertar(E,L,N2,R).
```